# Disable screen reading on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, accessibility

My father accidentally enabled this feature on his iPhone and now we don't know where to turn this off.

This button will show a screen reading feature I think for the blind or visual impaired people.

[image]

We tried the Accessibilities section, the General Settings but cannot find a way to disable it.

Can anyone help us to turn this feature off.

Comment: Have you tried Settings > Accessibility, in Vision block Spoken Content.

Comment: Many thank you for your hint. We were able to find the setting using the keyword "Spoken Control" to turn it off.